# Trying to migrate a project to a new Google Cloud organization but how to make my organization selectable as a migration option?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity

I've created a new Google Cloud Identity for an organization, and I want to migrate a project (which is not currently associated with any organization) to the new organization.

When I go to Google Cloud Platform > IAM & Admin > Settings and choose the Migrate option for my project, there are no organizations to choose from.

When I go to Google Cloud Platform > IAM & Admin > Identity & Organization it says "Page not viewable for projects. To view this page, select an organization." There is a SELECT link, but there are no organizations to select, so clicking on it does nothing.

How do I make my new organization available as an option for migration?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that a final step in creating an organization and making it possible to migrate an existing project to it is...

to create a new project from that organization, even if you have no need or desire to create a new project with it. Something about that action makes the organization migration-worthy, and after I did that I was able to migrate my previously-existing project to it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sorry about the terms, we see the spanish version of GCP console, and pheraps my google menu names and concept translations are not 100% accurates.

Perhaps it's to late, but we are now in the google madness ecosystem and after hours and headaches I think we could resolve the same o similar problem.

Our situation:

We have a google account (let's call it "A"), where we have some google products and the last is GKE cluster, so we use "Google Cloud Platform".

The problem begins when we need technical help assistance, because we detect that an empty GKE node (with no pods) has a high load average (about 1 - 1.2) at idle status.

Well, so we need technical help and the only way for this with Google is to pay for bronze help assistance (Important, if you pay for bronze, you could not be gold or silver ... why ?). Here is were the things start getting tight, and begins the google's madness and headache documentation and formularies.

1.- To get payed assistance you need activate the "role based assistance".

2.- To get "role based assitance" you need an "organization id".

3.- To get "organization id", you need Google Cloud Identity (free o premium) or Google Suite, where you can create an organization ... well ... documents said that the organization is created automatically.

4.- When you create "Google Cloud Identity", you are creating a new account ("B") distinct to "A".

Well, if you from account "A" go to "IAM" > "Identity and organization", chose to register a "Could identity", then start an wizard to create a new account linked to a domain name, and a billing data.

When you finish this process (where you had to change your DNS, or upload a file to check the authenticity of your domain), then you have a new account in Google Cloud (B), that is different from "A" ... so ... is so difficult for people in Google to transform "A" in "B" and not create 2 differents accounts ?

Now the problem is that your proyect and issues are in "A" account, and you have a new and clean "B" account with "Cloud identity".

Here, at this moment, you have 3 ways:

a) To say: "ohhhh my good, this is enough for me, who was the narrow mind that planned this madness method ?. I don't want this hell. I go to other provider. Good bye google."

b) From account "B", select your domain / organization (is the same), go to "IAM" > "Identity and organization", and there appears "Migrate projects and invoice accounts". Here you can send and invitation to the email of "A" account to move all projects (not selectable one by one) and the invoice method. User account "A" must accept the migration. Warning !!! Once a project is migrated to a domain, this cannot be undone.

c) From account "A", from the main page of your project and choose "add a member" or "add people to this project", then send an invitation to the email of account "B", and choose role as "owner of the project". User of account B will receive an email for accepting the invitation. Then, "B" can see the proyect in his panel, and inside move the proyect with no organization, to the B's organization.

Yes this was long, and a hell. But this is how we can move a project in an account "A" with no organization, to an organization to contract an assistance help service to Google.

The next problem is to get assistance ... when the forms lets you contract the bronze assistance service, then they informs you that this is a request that will lasts 5 days...

Really and sorry but there were moments where I was thinking to choose option "a".

Answer (score 1):

You will want to migrate the project in "A" to the Cloud Identity Organization "B". This is very simple using this document [1](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing).

You will use either G Suite or Cloud Identity (CI), not both. CI is an Identity as a Service for users that do not have a G Suite subscription. If one has a G Suite subscription then the Organization is automatically created. If not using G Suite then one will need to create the CI and Organization [2](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization).

Google does offer the paid support options mentioned. However, there are also other options such as partners for support on GKE, CI, G Suite, and overall GCP that do not incur a fee [3](https://www.doit-intl.com/). What you have described in this post is a common support scenario.

Answer (score 0):

According to [migrating-projects-billing](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing) document. 
You can try following commands:

Find out your organizations list:

```
gcloud organizations list
```

Move project to another organizations

```
gcloud alpha projects move PROJECT_ID --organization ORGANIZATION_ID
```

Comment: The problem is that there are no organizations in my list. I'm trying to get my organization into the list. When I do "gcloud organizations list" it says "Listed 0 items."

Perhaps the problem is that I think I've created an organization, but I haven't? I have created a Google Cloud Identity with a G Suite Business account.

Comment: Do you assign your self as organizations super  admin ?

Comment: Yes. When I look at the Super Admin role, I noticed a lot of boxes in the Privileges section weren't checked and weren't updatable, so I also made a new role with every single privilege checked and assigned my userid that role, but my organization still doesn't appear in the list.

Comment: @page23 do you have any news ? I am curious, if the problem persist probably you should contact Google Cloud Support (https://cloud.google.com/support/) to check your account and organization in details.